# Matlab: Getting a list of vectors

Tags: matlab

I have a single row matrix `theta` in Matlab with a couple hundred values; I would like to create a vector for each value in `theta`. Preferably I can simply store these values in a list so I can take dot products of individual elements in the list lator; how would I go about doing this?

For now, the code I have is

```
arrayfun(@(x) [sin(x),0,cos(x)],thetas,'UniformOutput',false);
```

which generates a bunch of `[1x3 double]`'s.

Comment: Are you just asking how to take the dot product using your big array?

Comment: @MrE, not yet, I need to actually know how to create the big array first, but that would be my next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output to your code is a cell array, whose elements are the 1x3 vectors you wanted. So suppose you assigned `A = arrayfun(@(x) [sin(x),0,cos(x)],thetas,'UniformOutput',false);` as you have up there. The vector corresponding with the ith element of array `thetas` may be accessed with `A{i}`. At this point you could use a `for` loop to construct a matrix whose ith column is the vector corresponding to the ith element of `thetas`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a cell array, you can also just create a numeric array of size `numberOfThetas-by-3`, like so:

```
A = [sin(thetas);zeros(size(thetas));cos(thetas)]'; %'# make n-by-3 by transposing
```

To calculate the dot product between any two vectors `i` and `j`, you can write

```
dotProduct = sum(A(i,:).*A(j,:));
```

Comment: Since the OP says `thetas` is a row vector, you will need to either use a transpose or `(:)` on each `thetas` argument first to get an N-by-3 matrix.

Comment: The important point to recognize is that when your list of vectors is really a list of vectors all of which have the same size and shape, then just make a matrix. Every row (or column) of that matrix will be a vector. Don't make a cell array of them. Now your dot products just become a matrix multiply, a VERY efficient thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to unnecessarily construct `for` loops to re-build the matrix as suggested by strictlyrude27. There is a nice inbuilt function [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell2mat.html) that does this for you in a single line.

Say your `A` is a `100` element cell, each of which holds a `1x3` vector. If you wanted to collect them such that each cell of `A` is a separate row, the command is simply

```
matrixA = cell2mat(A(:));
```

Comment: It's much more efficient too.